# Month Wise yearly Data sorting laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database

I have two table employess and attendances

- Now i have to fetch monthly data of full year, where year will be dynamic,
- I have to use relation between these two because i need name from employees table and attendance_status_id from attendances table
- Mothly data need to fetch based on in_time column which is in attendances table,
- Relation between these two table is in attendances table there is a column name employees_id
- Employee 1 JAN => 764 FEB => 478 MAR => 323
- Employee 2 JAN => 764 FEB => 478 MAR => 323
- Employee 3 JAN => 764 FEB => 478 MAR => 323

MY code

```
$employees = Employees::with('Attendance')->pluck('id');
    $emp_att_data = [];

    foreach ($employees as $employee)
    {
        $emp_att_data[] .= Attendance::select(DB::raw("(COUNT(*)) as count"), 
        DB::raw("MONTHNAME(in_time) as monthname"))->whereYear('in_time', date('Y'))- 
        >where('employees_id', '=', $employee)->groupBy('monthname')->orderBy('monthname')- 
        >get();
    }
```